# Transferring files via WiFi between two Windows machines

Tags: windows-10, wifi-transfer

I'd like to transfer 200gb of files between two Win10 laptops wirelessly. What would be the most time-saving option?

Comment: Which options have you considered? Are they in the same local network… or over the Internet? What type of wireless network? Please show us your research and a few more details. As it stands, this question is not answerable or too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both laptops are in the same location and this will not be happening across the Internet:

1. Join both laptops to the same wireless network.
2. Follow my detailed instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1466450/how-to-transfer-a-large-amount-of-data-between-two-windows-10-laptops/1466798#1466798) for using a shared folder and Robocopy to rapidly move your files across the network.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the process, where exactly, are the detailed instructions?

Comment: @Ramhound In the dupe originally posted as a link in the answer 

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - The original revision of this answer contain no such link.  Why isn't this just a duplicate of that question if the answer is the same?